# Failed to bind to '127.0.0.1:6600': Address already in use

Tags: mpi, ubuntu-12.10, mpd

I'm using ubuntu 12.10 for my MPI(message passing interface) configuration I have installed mpd after installation I have start mpd, it is started normally no error message display but when I'm trying to run the command  "mpd &" it gives me error message "Failed to bind to '127.0.0.1:6600': Address already in use" I have tried many solutions but the result is same.

> root@ub0:~# service mpd start
>
> Starting Music Player Daemon mpd
>   [ OK ]  root@ub0:~# service mpd restart
>
> Stopping Music Player Daemon mpd
>   [ OK ]   Starting Music Player Daemon mpd
>   [ OK ]   root@ub0:~# mpd &
>
> [1] 2881 root@ub0:~# Failed to bind to '127.0.0.1:6600': Address
>   already in use
>
> [1]+  Exit 1                  mpd
>
> root@ub0:~#

Comment: This question would likely be a better fit for [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/) as Stack Overflow is dedicated to authoring software. But, the error means that there is already a process with an open listener for that address and port and 2 processes can't listen to it at the same time. Perhaps an instance of `mpd` is already running. Or, it's not the only application on your system configured to use that port.

Comment: "I have tried many solutions": it would be best to list the solutions you've tried!

Comment: Belongs on unix.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

If you're using an old enough version of MPICH, the launcher is called MPD, which appears to conflict with something else you have installed on your system. I could try to help you with that, but the best answer is that you're using a very old version of MPICH and you should update. 3.1.1 came out yesterday. Give that a shot.

Comment: my mpch2 version is 1.4.1

Comment: Yes. That's a very old version. I would suggest updating as it's now much easier to launch. MPD is no longer necessary.